# Missing library on java.library.path trying to deploy executable JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm attempting to execute an executable JAR I generated using Eclipse for a Slick2D game project I'm trying to deploy, and I keep getting an error saying:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl64 in java.library.path
```

I followed the Slick2D setup to the letter when setting up the project months ago. But up until now, I've always run through Eclipse, and have never attempted to run through a JAR.

To generate the JAR, I chose Export -> Runnable JAR, and I chose to package the required libraries into the JAR. I then tried to execute the JAR from the command line as so:

```
java -jar JAR_NAME.jar
```

After receiving the above error, I tried many different methods of getting this so-called lwjgl64 library onto the java.library.path, but to no avail.

So far I've tried:

1. Changing the native library location of lwjgl.jar in my Slick2D user library to the folder containing the lwjgl-natives-*.jar files, but those only have the 32-bit definitions in them, and I figured it was looking for a DLL, so...
2. I ran the following command instead:

   > java -jar JAR_NAME.jar -Djava.library.path="C:\slick2d"

But this produced the same result, even though that directory contains lwjgl64.dll, among other files.

3. I tried copying all of the dll/so files from C:\slick2d into a folder called natives in a source folder in Eclipse and using the following code to set it as the java.library.path:

> System.setProperty("java.library.path", "libs");
>
> System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("libs/natives").getAbsolutePath());

But this just resulted in yet another error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\packetpirate\workspace\GZS Redux\target\libs\natives\lwjgl64.dll
```

Does anyone have any insight into this problem? I'm not great at building projects, especially in Eclipse, so I've always had trouble with linking dependencies. I've thought of converting my project to Maven, but I wouldn't know where to start and how to set it up.

**EDIT:** I realized that the libs/natives folder was not copied to the target folder when I generated my JAR, and after copying it over, I was able to run the JAR, but I still get similar errors related to jinput-dx8_64 and jinput-raw_64, which are also in the same folder. It doesn't seem to affect the game's behavior, though...

Also, although I know this is a Slick2D specific thing... it seems to be loading my assets twice. The only way I can see this happening is if the Loading state is entered twice, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: `-Dprop=value` (like other JVM options) must be specified BEFORE `-jar file` (or the main-class name) not after.

Comment: How would I specify that command when building the JAR, then?

Comment: I wasn't talking about building. To _run_ (the code in) a jar _with a sysprop set_, do e.g. `java -Djava.library.path=mypath -jar myjar` rather than `java -jar myjar -Djava.library.path=mypath` as you did in 2. This only fixes the property setting, it does not fix the file(s) being missing.

Comment: Did you consider using the maven assembly plugin?
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

This easily builds your application with all neccessary dependencies. From my experiences I'd say that the  Export -> Runnable JAR in eclipse will not be enough for building a slick2d project due to the native requirements of the lwjgl parts (correct me if i'm wrong)